tauri v2.0でtauri-plugin-oauthのインストールが失敗する
Windows環境でTauriアプリにGoogle Oauth2.0の実装を試みているところです。
tauri-plugin-oauthを使えば簡単にGoogle Oauth2.0の実装ができると思い
以下のコマンドでtauri-plugin-oauthをインストールしようとして失敗しました。
(tauri-plugin-oauthのほかに良いライブラリがあれば教えてほしいです。)
cargo add tauri-plugin-oauth

webkit2gtk-sysパッケージのバージョンの競合しているようで。これが原因で依存関係の解決に失敗しています。
異なるバージョンのwebkit2gtk-sysが同じネイティブライブラリweb_kit2にリンクしようとして失敗する?
この解決方法をだれかご教示いただけますか？
C:\WORK\tauri-js-oauth-v1.0\src-tauri> cargo add tauri-plugin-oauth
    Updating crates.io index
      Adding tauri-plugin-oauth v0.0.0-alpha.0 to dependencies
    Updating crates.io index
error: failed to select a version for `webkit2gtk-sys`.
    ... required by package `wry v0.18.3`
    ... which satisfies dependency `wry = "^0.18.3"` of package `tauri-runtime-wry v0.9.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `tauri-runtime-wry = "^0.9.0"` of package `tauri v1.0.0`
    ... which satisfies dependency `tauri-plugin-oauth = "^0.0.0-alpha.0"` of package `tauri-js-oauth-v10 v0.1.0 (C:\WORK\madchat\tauri-js-oauth-v1.0\src-tauri)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.18` are: 0.18.0

the package `webkit2gtk-sys` links to the native library `web_kit2`, but it conflicts with a previous package which links to `web_kit2` as well:
package `webkit2gtk-sys v2.0.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `ffi = "^2.0.1"` of package `webkit2gtk v2.0.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `webkit2gtk = "=2.0.1"` of package `tauri v2.0.1`
    ... which satisfies dependency `tauri = "^2.0.0"` of package `tauri-js-oauth-v10 v0.1.0 (C:\WORK\madchat\tauri-js-oauth-v1.0\src-tauri)`
Only one package in the dependency graph may specify the same links value. This helps ensure that only one copy of a native library is linked in the final binary. Try to adjust your dependencies so that only one package uses the `links = "web_kit2"` value. For more information, see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/resolver.html#links.      

failed to select a version for `webkit2gtk-sys` which could resolve this conflict


これら tauri-plugin-oauth v0.0.0-alpha.0, Specifying Dependencies, tauri-plugin-oauth/Cargo.toml の情報によると tauri-plugin-oauth は tauri v2.0 には対応していないようです。こちらの Issue is tauri-plugin-oauth compatible with tauri v2? #25 では crates.io release ではなく リポジトリの開発中ブランチを入れるようにという回答があります。

コメントいただきありがとうございます。 正式版が出るまで待ちました。 先週、開発者のFabian-Lars氏がtauri2.0に対応すると思われるtauri-plugin-oauthのバージョン2.0を正式に公開したようです。 src-tauriフォルダに移動し”cargo add tauri-plugin-oauth@=2.0.0”のコマンド実行したところインストールができました。 ですが今のところ、下記URLの方法でGoogle Oauth2.0のログインする方法を確立できていません。https://crates.io/crates/tauri-plugin-oauth/2.0.0

@kunif 曰く

これら tauri-plugin-oauth v0.0.0-alpha.0, Specifying Dependencies, tauri-plugin-oauth/Cargo.toml の情報によると tauri-plugin-oauth は tauri v2.0 には対応していないようです。こちらの Issue is tauri-plugin-oauth compatible with tauri v2? #25 では crates.io release ではなく リポジトリの開発中ブランチを入れるようにという回答があります。

